# Aggregation with MySQL CASE Expression

Tags: mysql, case

I have the following query to group "open sales quotes" records by date, and I've added some `CASE` expressions to break the total open quote amounts into 4 additional columns:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(quotes.created_at) AS date, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT quotes.entity_id) AS quote_open, 
    SUM(quote_items.row_total) AS quote_open_mrc, 
    CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 0 < 50 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT quotes.entity_id) END AS quote_open_50, 
    CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 50 < 75 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT quotes.entity_id) END AS quote_open_5075, 
    CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 75 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT quotes.entity_id) END AS quote_open_75,
    CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close IS NULL THEN COUNT(DISTINCT quotes.entity_id) END AS quote_open_noclose

FROM `sales_quote_item` AS `quote_items`

INNER JOIN `sales_quote` AS `quotes` 
    ON quotes.entity_id = quote_items.quote_id 

WHERE (quote_items.sku like '05-%') 
    AND (quotes.is_quotation = 1) 
    AND (quotes.quote_status NOT IN ('won', 'lost', 'expired')) 
    AND (quotes.quote_type = 'prod_serv_base_rec') 

GROUP BY 
    `date`
;
```

But this is not returning the correct results:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
| date       | quote_open | quote_open_mrc | quote_open_50 | quote_open_5075 | quote_open_75 | quote_open_noclose |
+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 2014-09-25 |          2 |       209.9000 |             2 |               2 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-09-29 |          1 |        95.4300 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-09-30 |          5 |       943.4500 |             5 |               5 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-02 |          1 |        70.9700 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-03 |          1 |       105.8300 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-06 |          1 |       197.3800 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-07 |          2 |      1430.1800 |             2 |               2 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-08 |          4 |      1185.5100 |             4 |               4 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-09 |          1 |        57.4800 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-13 |          1 |        73.1000 |             1 |               1 |          NULL |               NULL |
| 2014-10-14 |          2 |       326.6800 |             2 |               2 |             2 |               NULL |
| 2014-10-15 |          2 |      1294.8300 |             2 |               2 |          NULL |               NULL |
+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I'm not sure how to properly use a `CASE`, but in effect what I want is to see the spread of `quote_open` across difference "buckets" in the same result set. Therefore, the 4 bucket columns should add up to its `quote_open` amount on each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE WHEN` syntax is wrong. Try:

```
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 0 
                         AND quotes.percentage_to_close < 50 
                    THEN quotes.entity_id 
                  END) AS quote_open_50, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 0 
                         AND quotes.percentage_to_close < 50 
                    THEN quotes.entity_id 
                  END) AS quote_open_50, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 50 
                         AND quotes.percentage_to_close < 75 
                    THEN quotes.entity_id 
                  END) AS quote_open_5075, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 75 
                    THEN quotes.entity_id 
                  END) AS quote_open_75, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close IS NULL 
                    THEN quotes.entity_id 
                  END) AS quote_open_noclose
```

See [this simplified fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c43620/2).

Comment: This is great! When I first set out to learn about CASE I saw examples with what looked like shorthand expressions (eg: `>=0 < 50`), but now I see how that produces bad results. Also, it makes much more sense to count the results of the CASE expression. I simply didn't know that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is badly written:

```
CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 0 < 50
```

This'll be parsed more like

```
CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= (0 < 50)
CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= (true)
CASE WHEN quotes.percentage_to_close >= 1
```

You can't write a multi-comparison like that, Try something more like

```
CASE WHEN (a >= 0) AND (a <= 50)
```

instead.